# Is it possible to put an upper type bound mandating that a class has a concrete definition of a member type?

Tags: scala, generics, abstract-type

Let's consider:

```
 trait Abstract { 
    type T 
    def get :T
    def set(t :T) :Unit
 }

 class Concrete[X](var x :X) extends Abstract { 
     override type T = X 
     override def get :T = x
     override def set(t :T) = x = t
 }

 class Generic[M <: Abstract](val m :M) {
     def get :M#T = m.get
     def set(t :M#T) :Unit = m.set(t)
     def like[N <: Abstract](n :N) :Generic[N] = new Generic(n)
     def trans[N <: Abstract](n :N) :N#T = like[N](n).get
 }
```

Class `Generic` rightfully won't compile here because M#T can be literally any type in existence and not m.T. This can be 'fixed' in two ways:

```
     def set(t :m.T) :Unit = ???
```

or

```
     class Generic[M <: Abstract with Singleton]
```

First is unfeasible because in practice `Generic` might not even have an instance of `M` to use its member type (which happens in my real-life case), and passing around path dependent types in a compatible way between classes and methods is next to impossible. Here's one of the examples why path-dependent types are too strong (and a huge nuissance):

```
val c = new Concrete[Int](0)
val g = new Generic[c.type](c)
c.set(g.get)
```

The last line in the above example does not compile, even though `g :Generic[c.type]` and thus `get :c.type#T` which simplifies to `c.T`.

The second is somewhat better, but it still requires that every class with a `M <: Abstract` type parameter has an instance of `M` at instantiation and capturing `m.T` as a type parameter and passing everywhere a type bound `Abstract { type T = Captured }` is still a huge pain.

I would like to put a type bound on `T` specifying that only subclasses of `Abstract` which have a concrete definition of `T` are valid, which would make `m.T =:= M#T` for every `m :M` and neatly solve everything. So far, I haven't seen any way to do so.
I tried putting a type bound:

```
 class Generic[M <: Abstract { type T = O } forSome { type O }]
```

which seemingly solved the issue of `set`, but fails with `trans`:

```
def like[N <: Abstract { type T = O } forSome { type O }](n :N) :Generic[N] = ???
def trans[N <: Abstract { type T = O } forSome { type O}](n :N) :N#T = ???
```

which seems to me like a clear type system deficiency. Additionally, it actually makes the situation worse in some cases, because it defines `T` early as `some O(in class Generic)` and won't unify it when additional constraints become available:

```
def narrow[N <: M { type T = Int }](n :N) :M#T = n.get
```

The above method will compile as part of class `Generic[M <: Abstract]`, but not `Generic[M <: Abstract { type T = O } forSome { type O}]`. Replacing `Abstract { type T = O } forSome { type O }` with `Concrete[_]` yields very similar results. Both of these classes could be fixed by introducing a type parameter for `T`:

```
 class Generic[M <: Abstract { type T = O }, O]
 class Generic[M <: Concrete[_]]
```

Unfortunately, in several places I rely on two-argument type constructors such as

```
trait To[-X <: Abstract, +Y <: Abstract]
```

and use the infix notation `X To Y` as part of my dsl, so changing them to multi-argument, standard generic classes is not an option.

Is there a trick to get around this problem, namely to narrow down legal type parameters of a class so that their member type (or type parameter, I don't care) are both expressible as types and compatible with each other?. Think of `M` as some kind of factory of values of `T` and of `Generic` as its input data. I would like to parameterize `Generic` in such a way, that its instances are dedicated to concrete implementation *classes* of `M`. Do I have to write a macro for it?

Comment: `M#T` means any type `T` for any `M`, you want `m.T` I do not understand what is wrong with using that?

Comment: Apparently he doesn't have a concrete `m` at hands in his real use-case. @Turin, I suggest you explain directly what you really want to achieve and why having an `m` is not an option, because it seems strange.

Comment: @francoisr `val m :M` here you are asking for a concrete value of `M` you can not pass an abstract value to a constructor, because an abstract value doesn't even exist.

Comment: I know, but I think he doesn't want to require having such a value passed to the constructor. I can't figure out why that would be the case or if it would even make sense though. He'll need to clarify IMHO.

Comment: My concrete use case here could be summed up thus: I have a mapping/format class/object `Mapping[T]` which formats/parses `T`. Then, I have the data used by this object as its input `Data[M <: Mapping[_]]`. If a particular implementation of `Mapping` is a singleton object, then everything is fine and I can use its self type. If it is a class - and I want to support it - I don't have access to its instance in the place I create the data for it. If I had, the whole focus on type safety would be moot, because I could assemble everything in one go.

Comment: Furthermore: path-dependent types are path-dependent; if I had a `m.T`, then I could not pass values of `T` even to `n = m`; I couldn't write `def m[N <: M](n :N) = ??? //use 'm.T'/'M#T' with `n``. Which, since `N#T <: m.T` if `M` defines `T` as a concrete type, I should/would like to be able to do.

Comment: So, to answer the Luis's question from the first comment: first, as stated, I don't have access to m; second, I want `Generic` to work not only with singleton objects extending `Abstract`, but also normal, concrete classes (which must have a concrete definition of `T`). Type `T` here is the parsed/mapped type (even as simple as `String`) which is created freely and has absolutely no need of being path dependent, because from the point of view of all classes in the example, instances of `T` are interchangable.

Comment: "and passing everywhere a type bound `Abstract { type T = Captured }` is still a huge pain" That's what the `Aux` pattern is for.

Comment: Could you please provide a full implementation of what you're trying to do, even if that does not compile? I think it would help us help you.

Comment: I can't reproduce couple of places "This can be 'fixed' in two ways: ... or `class Generic[M <: Abstract with Singleton]`" With `Singleton` it still doesn't compile https://scastie.scala-lang.org/SV4oEUxCRpS1dSZYAscnEQ "Here's one of the examples why path-dependent types are too strong... The last line in the above example does not compile" The code seems to compile with path-dependent types https://scastie.scala-lang.org/ZTEqcKHxQGioYH0mYVvMtA I second requests to provide a full implementation in order to clarify the question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly why you're saying that using a path dependent type will be annoying here, so maybe my answer will be completely off, sorry about that.

What's the problem with this?

```scala
class Generic[M <: Abstract](val m: M) {
  def get: M#T = m.get
  def set(t: m.T): Unit = m.set(t)
}

object Generic {
  def like[N <: Abstract](n: N): Generic[N] = new Generic(n)
  def trans[N <: Abstract](n :N): N#T = like(n).get
}

class Foo
val f = new Generic(new Concrete(new Foo))
f.set(new Foo)
```

You're saying you won't always have an instance `m: M`, but can you provide a real example of exactly what you want to achieve?

Comment: 1. For the use case example, see my comment to the question. 2. Path dependent types get reaaly messy once you start passing them on; you can declate a `val m` in a method, use it as a constructor parameter and  `m.T` as the the type parameter, and you end up with a member which formally conforms to `m.T` but can't be used as such with the actual `m` - see my edited question.